# How can I add scrolling functionality to my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my navigation buttons to scroll to parts of the page as needed on click. How can I do this?

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.profile-id {
  position: center;
}

form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee Inline' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<header>
  <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 48pt; margin-top: 3%;"> New Wave Design Studios</p>
</header>

<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Bungee Inline';
    background-image: url(https://arielle.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/wave-photography-dark-2.jpg), url(http://imageshack.com/a/img922/4958/Ca6YSO.jpg), url(http://imageshack.com/a/img923/1588/duLIdx.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top, 100% 300px, 0% 870px;
    background-size: 100% 380px, 40%, 42%;
  }
</style>

<p style="margin: 10% 50% 10% 5%; font-size: 14pt; text-align: justified;"> NWDS set up shop in sunny So-Flo. The company was set up with the intention of coding an array of projects to prepare a strong, diverse portfolio for it's founder: Armando F III. With the knowledge from the FreeCodeCamp curriculum and a degree in software
  development, Armando hopes to build NWDS and make a breakout appearence in the software scene.
  <br></br>
  @JadeCoder
</p>

<p style="margin: 10% 5% 10% 50%; font-size: 14pt; text-align: justified;"> You can contact Armando through his freelance portfolio on Upwork by clicking
  <a href="https://www.upwork.com/fl/armandofrias" target="_blank">Here.</a>
</p>

<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 14pt;"> <u>Projects</u> </p>

<a href="http://workinprogress.agency/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/424x283q90/922/l43R2Y.jpg" alt="Nuclear Plant" align="left" style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 25px" height="300px" width="400px">
</a>

<a href="http://workinprogress.agency/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1020x680q90/924/2VMA4f.jpg" alt="SpaceX Launch" align: "center" style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 25px" height="300px" width="500px">
</a>

<a href="http://workinprogress.agency/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/275x183q90/923/KfsrjN.jpg" alt="Code" align: "right" style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 25px" height="300px" width="400px">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use my own script, I hope this works for you.

Make sure to include jQuery in your `<head>` tag like this:

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - $('.header').outerHeight(true)
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

Doing it this way, you can still control what happens if a user (let's say) scrolls:

```
$(function() {

    // previous code

    $(window).on('touchmove wheel mousewheel', function(e) {
        if ( e.type == "wheel" || e.type == "touchmove") {
            $('html, body').stop();
        }
    });
});
```

This way, the animation will stop whenever the user starts scrolling manually (while the animation is still running).